# Convert "select all that apply" to binary choices

Tags: r, survey

I have a data frame of survey responses, and some of the columns are questions where participants can select multiple answers ("select all that apply").

```
> age <- c(24, 28, 44, 55, 53)
> ethnicity <- c("ngoni", "bemba", "lozi tonga", "bemba tonga other", "bemba tongi")
> ethnicity_other <- c(NA, NA, "luvale", NA, NA) 
> df <- data.frame(age, ethnicity, ethnicity_other)
```

I would like those questions to be set up as binary-response items, so that each of the response choices (in this case `ethnicity` and `ethnicity_other`) becomes a column vector with either a 0 or a 1.

So far, I wrote a script that separates the individual unique responses into a list (`z`):

```
> x <- unique(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$ethnicity_other), " ")),    mode="list"))
> y <- unique(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$ethnicity), " ")), mode="list"))
>
> combine <- c(x, y)
>
> z <- NULL
> for(i in combine){
> if(!is.na(i)){
> z <- append(z, i)
>   }   
> }
```

I then created new columns from that list and filled them with NA values.

```
> for(elm in z){
>   df[paste0("ethnicity_",elm)]  <- NA
> }
```

So now I have 35 additional columns that I would like to fill with ones and zeros, depending on whether that column name (or part of that column name, as I prefix it with `ethnicity_`) can be found in the corresponding cell under `ethnicity` or `ethnicity_other.` I tried taking a stab at it a number of ways with no good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple ways to do this with `plyr` or `data.table`.

```
all_ethnicities <- unique(c(
    unlist(strsplit(df$ethnicity, " ")),
    unlist(strsplit(df$ethnicity_other, " "))
    ))

df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(id), function(x)
      table(factor(unlist(strsplit(paste(x$ethnicity, x$ethnicity_other), " ")),
                   levels = all_ethnicities)))

##    id ngoni bemba lozi tonga other tongi luvale
## 1  1     1     0    0     0     0     0      0
## 2  2     0     1    0     0     0     0      0
## 3  3     0     0    1     1     0     0      1
## 4  4     0     1    0     1     1     0      0
## 5  5     0     1    0     0     0     1      0

library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(df)

DT[, {
    as.list(
        table(
            factor(
                unlist(strsplit(paste(ethnicity, ethnicity_other),  " ")),
                levels = all_ethnicities)
            ),
        )
}, by = id]

##     id ngoni bemba lozi tonga other tongi luvale
## 1:  1     1     0    0     0     0     0      0
## 2:  2     0     1    0     0     0     0      0
## 3:  3     0     0    1     1     0     0      1
## 4:  4     0     1    0     1     1     0      0
## 5:  5     0     1    0     0     0     1      0
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Thank you so much. I'm a little unclear with how the ddply function works (function(x)...?), but I'll tinker around a bit more. I'm also trying to have each column prefixed with "ethnicity_". In my attempt I used the paste function in the creation of column names, but I'm having a hard time understanding where the column creation process is happening in your first explanation. Thanks again!!

Comment: @chrisnyoder `ddply` splits the data by the `id` variable (in this case just every row) then applies that function to each piece of data. So the input to the function `x` will be a 1 row `data.frame`. Try `ddply(df, .(id), function(x) browser() )` to explore what the environment of the function looks like. To set column names the easiest solution would be to do it after running this (ie. `out <- ddply(df, ...)` then `names(out)[names(out) != "id"] <- paste0("ethnicity_", names(out)[names(out) != "id"])`. I will add more to this answer later today when I have the time

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

First, you need something to store the ethnicities of each participant. My way to do it is to build a list of these:

```
ethnicities = sapply(X=df$ethnicity, FUN=function(response) {return (strsplit(as.character(response), " "))} )
```

For your particular example, we would have:

```
> ethnicities
[[1]]
[1] "ngoni"

[[2]]
[1] "bemba"

[[3]]
[1] "lozi"  "tonga"

[[4]]
[1] "bemba" "tonga" "other"

[[5]]
[1] "bemba" "tongi"
```

And then, to iterate over these to fill your data.frame **df**:

```
for (i in seq_along(ethnicities)) {
  for (eth in ethnicities[[i]]) {
    df[[paste0('ethnicity_',eth)]][i]=1
  }
}
```

The resulting value for **df** should be:

```
> df
  age         ethnicity ethnicity_other ethnicity_luvale ethnicity_ngoni ethnicity_bemba
1  24             ngoni              NA               NA               1              NA
2  28             bemba              NA               NA              NA               1
3  44        lozi tonga              NA               NA              NA              NA
4  55 bemba tonga other               1               NA              NA               1
5  53       bemba tongi              NA               NA              NA               1
  ethnicity_lozi ethnicity_tonga ethnicity_tongi
1             NA              NA              NA
2             NA              NA              NA
3              1               1              NA
4             NA               1              NA
5             NA              NA               1
```

There are other ways to do it. You could also pack these two *for loops* in sapply, but I have the feeling that the resulting code would not be more efficient (but would be more complicated to read!).

Does this help?

**edit:**

BTW, if you really want 0 instead of NA in your data.frame, it is as easy as changing your code initializing the added columns:

```
> for(elm in z){
>   df[paste0("ethnicity_",elm)]  <- 0 # instead of NA
> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `concat.split.expanded` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
## Combine your "ethnicity" and "ethnicity_other" column
df$ethnicity <- paste(df$ethnicity, 
                      ifelse(is.na(df$ethnicity_other), "", 
                             as.character(df$ethnicity_other)))
## Drop the original "ethnicity_other" column
df$ethnicity_other <- NULL

## Split up the new "ethnicity" column
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.expanded(df, "ethnicity", sep=" ", 
                      type="character", fill=0, drop=TRUE)
#   age ethnicity_bemba ethnicity_lozi ethnicity_luvale ethnicity_ngoni
# 1  24               0              0                0               1
# 2  28               1              0                0               0
# 3  44               0              1                1               0
# 4  55               1              0                0               0
# 5  53               1              0                0               0
#   ethnicity_other ethnicity_tonga ethnicity_tongi
# 1               0               0               0
# 2               0               0               0
# 3               0               1               0
# 4               1               1               0
# 5               0               0               1
```

The `fill` argument can easily be set to anything else you want. It defaults to `NA`, but here, I've set it to `0` since I think that's what you're looking for.